# Problem in aligning instance to tangent of curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals, instances

I'm trying to create a procedural rollercoaster in *Geometry Nodes*.
Usually a rollercoaster has this support in the rail:

[image]

I want it to follow the rotation of my curve, but no configuration of *Align Euler to Vector* seems to work. The best that I could do was like that:

[image]

The idea looks right:

[image]

But some sections of my rollercoaster are not very good, like that one:

[image]

I have a suspicion that the tangent of my curve does not correspond to the "natural" course of the tangent. Maybe I have to correct the normals of my curve somehow, but I don't know exactly if this is the problem and how to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, instead of a mesh, I would use a classic Bezier curve for this. The fewer points you reach, the better.

At the individual curve points you can then change the *tilt* accordingly.

[image]

Once your curve fits reasonably well, you can move on to the *Geometry Nodes*.

I have modified your example a bit.

First, I added a check that not only checks if the track is on the bottom, but also if it is underneath (this can happen with curves).

[image]

I also simplified the dummy track for the raycast, so that less geometry is generated.

[image]

Then I redesigned the rails of the track so that they fit exactly to the curve tilt, just like the middle part.

[image]

This solution is better for a track because you gain full control through your Bezier curve.

Only a clean curve is necessary for this.

PS: You can also slightly reduce the individual points in a Bezier curve, or add them where you need them. The tilt values can also be smoothed out if things get a bit jagged.

[image]

Comment: I prefered to use a mesh beacuse it looked easier to model the path. Using mirror and some stuffs of mesh editing I found it faster than starting with a standard bezier curve and adding points, carrying about the slope in every new point, etc.
Am I doing something stupid or there is an easier way to build my bezier? What If I simply convert my mesh into a Bezier? It would have the same effect as building the bezier from the scratch and trying to follow the path?

Comment: @MateusRocha This is what I did here: I converted your mesh line into a Bezier curve (but did not refine it in detail). I would also approach it the other way around, start with few points, and refine where necessary. The fewer points, the better. (And if your curve has a too low resolution, just increase it in the properties).

Comment: Thanks! I rearregended the nodes and rewrote everything to make sure that I understood the ideas, and it worked out!
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=1dRSDWGS" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/1dRSDWGS/)

Comment: Now I will remake the curve and the basic modeling is done :)